# android transfer video / image via bluetooth

Tags: android, stream, bluetooth

I have this project with an object tracking thingie. Now i use the webcam from the laptop to develop it but I will have to get an external camera when I will move it on the platform.

I was wondering if I can use the phone's camera to stream the video to the laptop to be processed via bluetooth.

But i do not know if that would be fast enough to maintain a decent framerate.